# How to convert this for loop to a Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, opencv, list-comprehension, image-resizing

My question is two parts, but first some background.

I'm trying to loop through a list of images and essentially standardize the size of each using cv2.resize. I was doing this successfully with the following for loop but the number of images has increased, and will continue to do so, resulting in my kernel crashing. I've tried running this code in both Spyder (Python 3.7) and Jupyter Notebook but to no avail.

```
for i in range(len(image_list)):
    image_list[i] = cv2.resize(image_list[i], (200,200))
```

List comprehension isn't very intuitive to me; however, I tried to convert the code above but wasn't successful. This is my attempt:

```
image_list2 = [cv2.resize(image_list, (200,200)) for i in range(len(image_list))]
```

1. What changes should I make to the second block of code?
2. Is converting the first block of code (for loop) to list comprehension something that would help avoid my kernel from crashing? I believe I'm overloading the RAM on my CPU by having so many images stored in 'image_list' - currently ~50,000 but this number may triple.

Thank you in advance for the help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: how it is not successful? can you explain how your result is different from the result of list comprhension?

Comment: why are you storing the results into a list? what are you doing with the data afterwards? maybe it would be better to resize each one and write the results to disk for each iteration... then read the whole directory again if you need to use them all at once

Comment: "I was doing this successfully with the following for loop but the number of images has increased, and will continue to do so, resulting in my kernel crashing" how does a list comprehension address this issue?

Comment: How are you building the original `image_list`? From a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code seems wrong too.
You shouldn't resize `image_list`, you should resize `image_list[i]`.

For the second block of code,

```
image_list2 = [cv2.resize(image, (200,200)) for image in image_list]
```

I'm not so sure if list comprehension will solve your problem though. How about saving the new resized image in a file every iteration and loading it later?

Comment: With regard to my first block of code: my apologies for the typo. I was in fact resizing each image within the list. I've corrected my initial post.

My concern with saving each new resized image (either locally or to Google Drive, etc.) is that they will take up a lot of space. However, it's a solution I'm willing to test on a small sample of images later today. Thank you and I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

you're sending the whole image_list to cv2.resize, when you only want to send one image at a time *from* the list.

```
for i in range(len(image_list)):
    image_list[i] = cv2.resize(image_list[i], (200,200))
```

Comment: That's actually what I had on my end and it was a typo. I edited my initial question. My apologies.

Do you have any ideas as to how I can make this code more efficient? List comprehension was just a thought but I'm open to anything.

Comment: @SpencerK You'll find the `for` loop is as efficient as anything, list comprehension isn't going to make it faster. The efficiency you're looking for is going to be in how you build that original image_list. If you can chunk the data into, for example 500 images at a time, then your processing should stabilize. Also, you may want to make sure that you aren't resizing files twice.